# Convert Cyrillic HTML tags to Latin via PHP

Tags: php, regex, cyrillic, transliteration, latin

**THIS IS NOT Regular expression to remove HTML tags! Read the question carefuly!**

I created a script to convert Cyrillic to Latin and Latin to Cyrillic.

Converting Latin to Cyrillic creates a lot of problems with HTML because the script also converts HTML elements. I created an algorithm that converts Cyrillic HTML to Latin and keeps everything within tags in Cyrillic.

The script works almost well, but either I have a memory problem or the while loop starts to spin indefinitely. Basically, the problem is up to the speed of the script.

```
public function html_tags() {
    $tags = explode(',', '!DOCTYPE,a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,area,article,aside,audio,b,base,basefont,bdi,bdo,big,blockquote,body,br,button,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,col,colgroup,data,details,dd,del,details,dfn,dialog,dir,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,font,footer,form,frame,frameset,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,head,header,hr,html,i,iframe,img,input,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,link,main,map,mark,meta,master,nav,noframes,noscript,object,ol,optgroup,option,output,p,param,picture,pre,progress,q,rp,rt,ruby,s,samp,script,section,select,small,source,span,strike,strong,style,sub,summary,sup,svg,table,tbody,td,template,textarea,tfoot,th,thead,time,title,tr,track,tt,u,ul,var,video,wbr');
    $tags = array_map('trim', $tags);
    $tags = array_filter($tags);
    return apply_filters('serbian_transliteration_html_tags', $tags);
}

public function fix_cyr_html($content){
    $content = htmlspecialchars_decode($content);

    $tags = $this->html_tags();
    
    $tags_cyr = $tags_lat = array();
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $tags_cyr[]='<' . str_replace($this->lat(), $this->cyr(), $tag);
        $tags_cyr[]='</' . str_replace($this->lat(), $this->cyr(), $tag) . '>';
        
        $tags_lat[]= '<' . $tag;
        $tags_lat[]= '</' . $tag . '>';
    }
    
    $tags_cyr = array_merge($tags_cyr, array('&нбсп;','&лт;','&гт;','&ндасх;','&мдасх;','хреф','срц','&лдqуо;','&бдqуо;','&лсqуо;','&рсqуо;','&сцарон;','&Сцарон;','&тилде;'));
    $tags_lat = array_merge($tags_lat, array('&nbsp;','&lt;','&gt;','&ndash;','&mdash;','href','src','&ldquo;','&bdquo;','&lsquo;','&rsquo;','ш','Ш','&tilde;'));
    
    $content = str_replace($tags_cyr, $tags_lat, $content);
    
    $lastPos = 0;
    $positions = [];

    while (($lastPos = mb_strpos($content, '<', $lastPos, 'UTF-8')) !== false) {
        $positions[] = $lastPos;
        $lastPos = $lastPos + mb_strlen('<', 'UTF-8');
    }

    foreach ($positions as $position) {
        if(mb_strpos($content, '>', 0, 'UTF-8') !== false) {
            $end   = mb_strpos($content, ">", $position, 'UTF-8') - $position;
            $tag  = mb_substr($content, $position, $end, 'UTF-8');
            $tag_lat = $this->cyr_to_lat($tag);
            $content = str_replace($tag, $tag_lat, $content);
        }
    }
    
    // Fix open tags
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(<[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9a-zA-Z\/\=\"\'_\-\s\.\;\,\!\?\*\:\#\$\%\&\(\)\[\]\+\@\€]+>)/iu', function($m){
        return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[1]);
    }, $content);
    
    // FIx closed tags
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(<\/[\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9a-zA-Z]+>)/iu', function($m){
        return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[1]);
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix HTML entities
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/\&([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9]+)\;/iu', function($m){
        return '&' . $this->cyr_to_lat($m[1]) . ';';
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix JavaScript
    $content = preg_replace_callback('/(?=<script(.*?)>)(.*?)(?<=<\/script>)/s', function($matches) {
            return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[2]);
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix CSS
    $content = preg_replace_callback('/(?=<style(.*?)>)(.*?)(?<=<\/style>)/s', function($matches) {
            return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[2]);
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix email
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9\_\-\.]+)@([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9\_\-\.]+)\.([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9]{3,10}))/iu', function($m){
        return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[1]);
    }, $content);

    // Fix URL
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}]{4,5}):\/{2}([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9\_\-\.]+)\.([\x{0400}-\x{04FF}0-9]{3,10})(.*?)($|\n|\s|\r|\"\'\.\;\,\:\)\]\>))/iu', function($m){
        return $this->cyr_to_lat($m[1]);
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix attributes with doublequote
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(title|alt|data-(title|alt))\s?=\s?"(.*?)"/iu', function($m){
        return sprintf('%1$s="%2$s"', $m[1], esc_attr($this->lat_to_cyr($m[3])));
    }, $content);
    
    // Fix attributes with single quote
    $content = preg_replace_callback ('/(title|alt|data-(title|alt))\s?=\s?\'(.*?)\'/iu', function($m){
        return sprintf('%1$s=\'%2$s\'', $m[1], esc_attr($this->lat_to_cyr($m[3])));
    }, $content);

    return $content;
}
```

The main question is whether and how can I convert bad HTML tags (Cyrillic HTML tags and attributes) to Latin and save all other text in Cyrillic?

```
<див цласс="цонтент">Мама воли бебу</див>   --->   <div class="content">Мама воли бебу</div>
```

Can it be achieved with regex or is there a faster / better solution?

Comment: Actually parsing [HTML with Regex is a bad idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). It will lead you always to problems you didn't think of in the first time. I think you would do better if you handle the file as [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), deconstrcut and rebuild it with converted tags, attributes and so on.

Comment: Yeah I know. I want to avoid regex but need some fast and better solution. Does DOM class can handle Cyrillic HTML tags? Or I need to open all HTML elements on the first place and transliterate text inside it?

Comment: Using `strip_tags` before doesn't works? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I don't know if it can handle that tbh, but I would expect yes. If not I would rather try other dom manipulating libraries/techniques than regexing around.

Comment: _“Does DOM class can handle Cyrillic HTML tags?”_ - what are “Cyrillic HTML tags” supposed to be in the first place, there is no such thing as `<див цласс="цонтент">` in actual HTML. Is that the actual input data you need to handle, or was that just supposed to be an example of how correct HTML gets messed up by your current approach? _“Or I need to open all HTML elements on the first place and transliterate text inside it?”_ - yes, you will need to recursively iterate over _all_ nodes, and only do any transliteration, when you encounter _text_ nodes.

Comment: I don't know who closed this question, they didn't read my question and the reason for closing is wrong and the post that was suggested is wrong. Please **REOPEN** this question. I'm not looking for a regex to remove tags but to correct the Cyrillic representation of the HTML tag to normal Latin HTML tags. Thanks!